# Strategic error on Python/Flask deploy

Tags: python-2.7, web-services, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm new to web development and deployment however I developed a web site using Python 2.7 and Flask. I can't get the site to load when the user hits the site.  When testing on the server using SSH the program starts like it did on my development PC but does not render the first template and shows this error:   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.   Use a production WSGI server instead.

In researching that error I found an article that says Flask is not meant for a multi-user public web environment. Further investigation said: If you want to run Flask in production, be sure to use a production-ready web server like Nginx, and let your app be handled by a WSGI application server like Gunicorn.

I think what this is telling me is:
Find a provider that supports Nginx.
Install Gunicorn and then configure it to run on that host.
Doing that should allow my program to run on the host server and be accessible to the world.

Would folks with experience with Python/Flask web apps please confirm the direction I should be heading as I can't afford to go down the wrong path again.

Comment: You're correct, you cannot use the built in server in Production. Almost any provider: AWS, Azure, Linode, Google Cloud, etc. will allow you to build a WSGI environment in like 5 minutes. I personally think it's easier to setup Flask with Apache but that's personal preference. Setting up Nginx will be just as simple, just find a tutorial using Google :) "setting up Flask with Nginx" should get you going.

Comment: THANK YOU - I think my current provider, A2 Hosting, supports Apache by default so if you think that'll work I'll head that direction - any tips based on that being your personal preference, as I said I'm a newbe so it all looks daunting, any input is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at www.brettjouwstra.me/flask_and_apache/ there I placed the general instructions I use to setup my webapps, including that site. Should get you started in the right direction. Obviously replace your generic addresses with your own. I would recommend that if all possible, use python 3, it's the future. If you NEED to use 2.7 you'll have to modify the instructions slightly.

Comment: Thank you again so much!! I'll get to the instructions ASAP - if I may ask another question, you mention getting to Python 3 - is there a big effort involved in converting an existing 2.7 program to a 3? Finally, is there a version of 3 that you recommend?  Again, thanks!

Comment: and one last one please- the directions show installing apache2 which I understand for your local system, but would you normally do that on a hosted server or will that already be there?

Comment: No easy way to say how difficult converting would be, it depends how complex and large your app is. In the long run it will be worth it though, that I am positive on. On a hosted server you'd have to install it unless your provider installs it by default. I host on AWS and Linode and they do no pre-install. If you attempt to install it and it's already there it won't hurt anything.

Comment: One last one - thanks for your patience  - when I SSH to my site to start the process you outline the first command apt-get update returns command not found - is there another flavor to try or is this strategy not supported by my host (yikes)?

Comment: Are you not using Ubuntu, what flavour of Linux are you using? I just assumed Ubuntu because it seems to be the most popular, but if you're using a different distro you'll need to adjust and/or find completely different instructions. Thanks

Comment: I'm using a provider called A2Hosting, looks like they're using CloudLinux OS- they told me on shared servers (which mine is) apt-get is not allowed  -- any ideas for that environment - it was suggested that I use flup, FCGI and .HTAccess - i gave that a try but am receiving the following error: Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. The server error log shows no errors.     THANK YOU!!!

Comment: After looking at your host's site, I would recommend paying the extra $1.08 and moving to the VPS option. It'll be hard, prolly impossible, to setup much of anything besides their canned options, drupal or wordpress, on the shared service.

Comment: wow great guidance - I'll do it ASAP - if I do that can I use your instructions - will the apt-get problem go away?  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!

Comment: Yes, on the vps option you’ll be able to use apt-get get any any other command you want/need

Comment: great thank you so much - I'm working on it now - I'm selecting Ubuntu 16.04 w/Webuzo - not sure exactly what Webuzo is but it sounds like a panel to manage stuff like cPanel has - does that sound like the choice you would make? Again THANK YOU for your patience and help - you have really been a life saver - THANK YOU

Comment: maybe one final question before trying to get this setup and work through your instructions again - can i load any thing on this server just like i do on by local pc, for example a file manger? if so do you have a favorite that you use or would recommend for a newbie?

Comment: *** UPDATE *** -- I worked through the instructions without issue but the site still shows the default page from the provider - I think the issue is path related - the instructions have the work done in /var/www which SSH allowed me to do and if I use ls all files I created are there.  If I use file manager or FTP I can't see or get to the /var directory - I do see a www directory and a public_html directory using file manager and FTP but can't cd to them using SSH - I would  redo the exact instructions but use one of those but can't reach them from SSH.  any ideas??  THANK YOU AGAIN!!

Comment: If you used something like WinSCP you can manipulate files in the secure directories, you just have to initiate your connection scp. Then you don't have to mess around with FTP or initiating file transfers through your terminal, etc.